# VBA Excel, assign formula to row in range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am new to VBA and wanted to ask if you could help me.
I have this VB6 code:

```
For i = 2 To rowCount - 2
        ' Fill Ji  with a formula(=MID(Fi,11,9)) and apply format.
        Set oRng = oSheet.Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(rowCount - 2, 10))
        **oRng.formula = "=MID(Cells(i,6),11,9)"**
        oRng.NumberFormat = "[$-F400]hh:mm:ss"
Next i
```

I want to assign a formula to the range 
Tried this code but, has a problem when I assign the formula. It doesn't recognizes the Cell(i,6) as Cell, but As string "Cell(i,6)".
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the loop as you're putting the formula into all cells at once:

```
    ' Fill Ji  with a formula(=MID(Fi,11,9)) and apply format.
    Set oRng = oSheet.Range(oSheet.Cells(2, 10), oSheet.Cells(rowCount - 2, 10))
    oRng.formulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC6,11,9)+0"
    oRng.NumberFormat = "[$-F400]hh:mm:ss"
```

Note: I added a +0 to your formula to convert text to true time values.

Comment: Thank you, you were helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try `"=MID(" & Cells(i,6).Address(False,False) &",11,9)"`
Include the Address part only if you want a relative reference